# How to run a c# function on page load from jQuery $( document ).ready()

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, document-ready

I am trying to play with Ajax a bit so i have created the following function.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Refreshed at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <fieldset>
        <legend>UpdatePanel</legend>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Panel created."></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        </fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So this above example from Microsoft. Now this works perfectly for me. what i want to do here is run the `Button1_Click` function on `$(document ).ready()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right thing to do, the doPostBack method will cause an endless loop.
document.Ready -> doPostBack -> Document.ready -> doPostBack. Etc..

You can do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   __doPostBack("Button1", null);
});
```

Comment: Can you show me what error you get in the F12 console please ?

Comment: Won't this just become an endless loop?  (Postback will cause document.ready, which will in turn cause postback etc..)

Comment: Yes that would seem right, The __doPostBack method is what I use in certain circumstances. I suppose using doPostBack in the document ready event is probably not the way to go about this